# Black screen after Suspend/Hibernate in Ubuntu 16.04 with GeForce 920MX, NVIDIA 390.77 and 4.15.0-32-generic

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

I get to a black screen/command after I suspend or hibernate my laptop. I tried every possible solution but I got no positive result. Details:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5
Kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic
Graphic Card: Nvidia GeForce 920MX
Installed Driver: Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 390.77 from nvidia-390 (open-source)
```

I tried 396.51, 384.130 (proprietary), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and got no luck. If you need I can post related logs.

Is this a bug? Is there a solution?

Comment: I would not use hibernate, its not stable, in fact Im sure its disabled by default. Suspend should work, works great for me. Have you tried the LTS kernel and not the HWE kernel ?

Comment: @hatterman Hi, thanks for your comment, btw i don't see points in your first part of your answer hence my problem still exist and yes it's disabled by default. i can verify my kernel is LTS. more suggestions?

Comment: 4.15 isnt the LTS kernel as far as I know, thats the HWE kernel. I would try the LTS kernel. That said, it could be the case that the bluetooth adapter has failed. Type lspci, can you see a bluetooth adapter in the list ?

Comment: @hatterman Sorry, i was wrong. i tired and i got a interface with gpu error, does it only work for integrated graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries of making suspend/hibernate work again, I had to reinstall ubuntu to make it work correctly again this time.

Before it I'd tried to check everything and install graphics driver first.

Comment: What **everything** you'd tried? Have you tried to use different kernels, including old that were using before the issue appeared?